# Use array inside multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, arduino, jagged-arrays

I've been looking at different answers and stuff (like jagged array) but I still cant understand how this would work (or if it even works). In the end, this should be which my arduino uses for writing> But that aside. Here's my problem:

I want to make an multidimensional array which represents all the letters from the alphabet. Each index has two arrays; one for directions and one for rotations. Something like this:

```
  |      0       |      1      |
0 | directions[] | rotations[] |
1 | directions[] | rotations[] |
................................
25| directions[] | rotations[] |
```

How would one accomplish this? Is it even accomplishable?
For now I'm using this in C#, but I have to convert it to C eventually. 
Any help or insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: New code with LetterData class and example values

```
public class LetterData
    {
        public int[] distance;
        public int[] rotation;
    }

    public LetterData[] sequence = new LetterData[25];

    void Start () 
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            sequence[i].distance = new int[2];
            sequence[i].rotation = new int[2];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simplifying?:

```
public class LetterData
{
    public DirectionsType[] Directions;
    public RotationsType[] Rotations;
}

LetterData[] myVar = new LetterData[25];
...
myVar[i].Directions = new DirectionsType[n];
...
myVar[i].Directions[k] = value;
```

Answer for EDIT:

```
public class LetterData
    {
        public int[] distance;
        public int[] rotation;
    }

public class MyClass
{
    public LetterData[] sequence = new LetterData[25];

    void Start () 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            sequence[i] = new LetterData();
            sequence[i].distance = new int[2];
            sequence[i].rotation = new int[2];
        }
    }
}

...

MyClass m = new MyClass();
m.Start();
```

Comment: This makes so much sense. How I missed this I'll never know.

Comment: Mark it as answer, and all shall be forgiven (until next booboo)!! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate. This kiss made my booboo go away.

Comment: On a side note here, how would I insert data in those (sub)arrays in the LetterData class? Something like LetterData[0] = {10,5}?

Comment: I just updated the answer with one possible solution...  other variants of course is to have List instead of array and thus you can just `.Add` to make easier, or improve `LetterData` class to make those setters and getters that guarantee that array or list is already instantiated (if size is known in case of the array).

Comment: Allrighty then. I prefer lists above arrays but I have to use it for Arduino and I'm not sure that its supported as Lists are in a different library.

Comment: Yeah, in that case the code above should do the trick, albeit requiring a bit of care to make sure all arrays are instantiated prior to use...

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but it seems to fail to find the object reference. I'm using it like your example. I will edit my question to show my recent code.

Comment: Here you go, you were missing `sequence[i] = new LetterData();`